# Pigeon hole principle application

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I am watching a lecture on pigeonhole principle at this [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eick163K5Eo&list=PL0862D1A947252D20).

[image]

At time 40:42, why does the instructor say that "either a will have 3 friends or 3 enemies". Why can't it be any of the other cases she mentions ?

Thanks.

Comment: you can't pose questions like that. Explain what the problem is, then what you don't understand. You can't link to a video so someone has to watch it to understand the problem.

Comment: I did not watch all of it! 30 seconds at most :)

Comment: yeah i guess, but still.. The point of the site is that people can then search the same question and find the answer, in this way it's impossible ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It can be, but in every case $a$ has **at least** $3$ friends or **at least** $3$ enemies, and that’s all that’s needed to make the rest of the argument work.

Answer (score 1):

She states the possible cases:
$$
\begin{array}{c:c}
\mbox{friends} & \mbox{enemies}\\
\hdashline\\
5 & 0\\
\hdashline\\
4 & 1\\
\hdashline\\
3 & 2\\
\hdashline\\
2 & 3\\
\hdashline\\
1 & 4\\
\hdashline\\
0 & 5
\end{array}
$$
So what she should have said was that A would have at least three either friends or enemies. There is no row above having both numbers less than 3 is another way of putting it.